# KeePassXC doesn't make a history after change an entry

Tags: keepassx

My database of KeePassXC is converted from KeePassX or KeePass 0.4, I am not sure. Each time changing password I could not see the backup in the history tab, is it matters to the database file? How to setup KeePassXC for automatically creating a history for the new password?

Answer (score 1):

From KeepassXC main view, go to Database -> Database Settings.

First, select *Security* from the left-side menu, and check the *Database format* setting on the *Encryption Settings* tab. You might still be using the older KDBX 3.1 format, which might disable some features.

Then select *General* from the left-side menu, and check the settings in the History Settings box. Make sure neither the "Max. history items" nor "Max. history size" are set to zero, as that would disable the history function.

Each password entry has its own separate history.

Comment: After checking I'm still using the old format, do I need to change to Argon 2 which is recommended?