# KeePassXC no entry history

Tags: keepassx, keepassxc

There seems to be **no entry history** whatsoever in my KeePassXC database, and entries seem to be **modified** (indicated as last modified; data doesn't seem to be changing) whenever they're used by the Firefox plugin.

[KeePassXC doesn't make a history after change an entry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652930/keepassxc-doesnt-make-a-history-after-change-an-entry) doesn't help: I cannot find any of the settings suggested in my KeePassXC.

The database format is correct, and history was working when I had the same database on Ubuntu. I'm now using Apple Macbook M2, latest KeePassXC 2.7.4.